# How does flying over synchronize clocks look like?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

I have a relatively (pun intended) simple conceptual question that has me going in circles as I begin my course work into Modern Physics. The question is straight forward enough:

> You are gliding over Earth's surface at a high speed, carrying your high-precision clock. At points X and Y on the ground are similar clocks, synchronized in the ground frame of reference. As you pass over clock X, it and your clock both read 0.
>
> 1. According to you, do clocks X and Y advance slower or faster than yours?
> 2. When you pass over clock Y, does it read the same time, an earlier time, or a later time than yours?

For part 1 I figure, by inertial frame of reference, all other clocks would appear to be running slower. Initially I thought this would apply to part 2, but the when over X, Y does not read 0. So my real question is: Will Y appear to run increasingly faster until I am directly over it, and slower as I get further away, and therefore have a later time? If so, does this then go against my statement that the clocks will appear to run slower from outside an inertial frame?

Comment: Caution: the quoted question is asking about the state of the clocks at a particular time in your frame of reference, *not* what they would *look* like as you passed over and light from them entered your eye. For an intuitive idea of how those differ, you can try [velocity raptor](http://www.testtubegames.com/velocityraptor.html) and toggle between "seen" and "measured" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed at that both X and Y run only corresponds to your relative velocity, not to your distance. So from your frame of reference both X and Y run slower than your clock, at the same, constant speed.

What Y and your clock show when you pass it is easiest answered from the earths frame of reference: You are moving at high velocity, so your clock runs slower, therefore Y will show a later time.

As you pointed out correctly, what looks like a paradoxon first is resolved, once you notice that X and Y are only synchronized in the earths frame of reference. So from your point of view at the moment you pass X, clock Y will not show 0.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, my issue was with changing reference frames. From the ground, clock Y was at some time > 0 when the glider and X are at 0. And, bc of reference, the glider's clock appears slower, thus it will always show a time less than Y's.?

Comment: in the ground frame of reference, both clocks are synchronized, that means at the time you pass X, Y shows 0 as well. but "at the time" only refers to time in ground frame here.

Comment: Thank you for  your patience and assistance. So, from the ground frame, the glider's clocks is slower, X and Y are synchronized, and therefore X and Y would both show a later time? Is it also then true that from the glider's frame, both X and Y would run slower, and thus always be behind?

Comment: from the ground frame: yes, after you passed X (at this point all clocks show 0) your clock will be behind the others. in your frame: yes, after you passed X (at this point your clock and X show 0) X will always be behind. however once you pass Y, as we learned from the ground frame, your clock will be behind Y (but run faster and will therefore catch up). The important point is: relativity always gives the same description for events that appear at the same position at the same time (when you pass X/Y), but not for events that appear on a different time or place (e.g. Y when you pass X)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which clock you pass first.

When you pass over the X-clock, both it and your own clock read zero.  The Y-clock (according to you) reads some time earlier than 0 if you've already passed over it, or some time later than 0 if you haven't passed over it yet.

According to you, both clocks run (equally) slow, and the Y-clock is either always ahead of the X-clock or always behind the X-clock, depending on which one you pass over first.

It is always best to start by drawing the spacetime diagram.  Here is the picture on the assumption that you pass the X-clock first.  The thick black line is you, the thick blue line is the X-clock, the thick orange line is the Y-clock, the thin black lines are your own surfaces of simultaneity, and the thin colored lines are surfaces of simultaneity according to the earthbound clocks.  Your clock and the X-clock read zero at $A$.  The $Y$-clock reads zero at $B$.  If you stare at the picture long enough, you'll see exactly what's happening.

[image]